# UITableView UITableViewController Detail View and UISegmentedControl how?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am currently adding Segmented Control in the viewDidLoad of the detail view and that is fine, but that means that I need to call back into TableViewController to act on it.

And realistically it is the table view navigator responsibility to do go through items in the table view? So I think it would have been better if I would add segmented control inside prepareForSegue when I am switching form table view to detail view? However when I attempt that detail view removes segmented control from navigation bar, so I suspect that either this is not a correct way or I am doing something wrong.

What is the correct way to do this?

Also is it possible to get default images for up down arrows for next/previous buttons similar to the ones used by email client?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add the control in prepareForSegue, because the destination controller's view hasn't been loaded yet at that time. Doing it in viewDidLoad is fine. I don't know what you mean by "I need to call back into TableViewController to act on it". What is the purpose of the segmented control?

Comment: the purpose is to got forward/backward in between details of rows in the table view but without going back to the table view first. Segmented control is a next, previous selector.
Basically how do I do select row at index... or do I need to pass pointer to elements to detail view so that it manages loading and reloading of data?

Comment: @user2009606, the usual way to get data back to the controller you came from is with delegate methods. The table view controller should set itself as the delegate of the detail controller when it creates it. The segmented control's action method would call the delegate method which would cause the table view controller to pass the next or previous item to the detail controller.

Comment: Thanks, I think it makes sense. I did it by passing data to detail view and detail reloading from it. Just because I did not know how it would look if I call delegate tableview to select another row from detail of a previous row only to go back to the detail view. More of a concern about visual aspects of these transitions.